# JMeter: Extract Multiple values from JSON responses and store it in variable(comma seperated)

Tags: jmeter

Can you please let me know efficient way to extract all ItemID from below Json response and store extracted values in a variable with coma separated.
Example: JsonResponse of a request.
[
{
"ItemID": "ITM40400002",
"deliveryId": "1",
},
{
"ItemID": "ITM40400003",
"deliveryId": "2",
},
{
"ItemID": "ITM40400002",
"deliveryId": "3",
}
]

Extracted Variable
Items = ITM40400002,ITM40400003,ITM40400002

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns the above JSON
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Names of created variables: anything meaningful, i.e. `foo`
   - JSON Path Expressions: `$..ItemID`
   - Match No: `-1`
   - Tick `Compute concatenation var`

   [image]
3. That's it, the JSON Extractor will extract all the ItemID attributes values and store them into `foo_ALL` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

Demo:

[image]

More information: [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor)